# Android mediaplayer play in background

Tags: java, android, android-studio, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am working on mediaplayer app, but i have problem with onDestroy methods, i need to continue with playing music when i minimalize the app. But when i do it stops playing and throws errors or when i comment it, it is playing in background but problem is that it doesnt stop even when i kill the app, i can controll it just with my notification controller, but when i destroy controller by swiping, it is playing and i have music in background without music player.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private MediaPlayerService player;
private boolean serviceBound = false;
private ArrayList<Audio> audioList;
private RWAdapter rwa;
private RecyclerView rv;

public static final String Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO = "com.example.rsabo.mp3player.PlayNewAudio";
public static final String Broadcast_PAUSE_AUDIO= "com.example.rsabo.mp3player.PauseAudio";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
    }

    loadAudio();
    initRW();

}

private void initRW(){
    if (audioList.size()>0) {
        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        ;
        rwa = new RWAdapter(audioList, getApplicationContext());
        rv.setAdapter(rwa);
        rv.addOnItemTouchListener(new MyTouchListener(this, new onItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int index) {
                playAudio(index);
            }
        }));
    }
}

//ulozi sa instancia
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("ServiceState", serviceBound);
}

//obnovi sa instancia tam kde bola naposledy ulozena
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    serviceBound = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("ServiceState");
}

//znici instanciu
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
//        if(serviceBound){
//            unbindService(serviceConnection);
//            player.stopSelf();
//        }
}

//viaze tuto triedu s prehravacom, nastavi hodnotu serviceBound na true ked sa vytvori spojenie
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection(){
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MediaPlayerService.LocalBinder binder = (MediaPlayerService.LocalBinder) service;
        player = binder.getService();
        serviceBound = true;

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service bound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        serviceBound = false;
    }
};

//Metoda pozrie ci je sluzba aktivna,
//ak nie je, do uloziska hodi arraylist s pesnickami, a spusti sluzbu
//ak je vlozi do uloziska novy audioIndex a posle spravu ze ma spustit pesnicku
private void playAudio(int audioIndex){
    if(!serviceBound){
        Ulozisko ulozisko = new Ulozisko(getApplicationContext());
        ulozisko.storeAudio(audioList);
        ulozisko.storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);

        Intent playerIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
        startService(playerIntent);
        bindService(playerIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    } else {
        Ulozisko ulozisko = new Ulozisko(getApplicationContext());
        ulozisko.storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
}

private void pauseAudio(){
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(Broadcast_PAUSE_AUDIO);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}


//nacita pesnicky z mobilu
private void loadAudio() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);

    if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        audioList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
            String album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
            String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
            audioList.add(new Audio(data, title, album, artist));
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
}


 }
```

MediaPlayerService

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener, MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener,
    AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 101;
private MediaSessionManager mediaSessionManager;
private MediaSessionCompat mediaSession;
private MediaControllerCompat.TransportControls transportControls;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private String mediaFile;
private int resumePosition;
private AudioManager audioManager;
private boolean hovor = false;
private PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener;
private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
private ArrayList<Audio> audioList;
private int audioIndex = -1;
private Audio activeAudio;
private final IBinder iBinder = new LocalBinder();
private PlayStatus status;

public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.example.rsabo.mp3player.ACTION_PLAY";
public static final String ACTION_PAUSE = "com.example.rsabo.mp3player.ACTION_PAUSE";
public static final String ACTION_PREVIOUS = "com.example.rsabo.mp3player.ACTION_PREVIOUS";
public static final String ACTION_NEXT = "com.example.rsabo.mp3player.ACTION_NEXT";
public static final String ACTION_STOP = "com.example.rsabo.mp3player.ACTION_STOP";

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return iBinder;
}


//pri vytvoreni zavola metody callStateListener(),registerJeNahlasReciever(), registerPlayNewAudio()
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    callStateListener();
    registerJeNahlasReciever();
    registerPlayNewAudio();
}

//podla priority zvuku v systeme zvysi zvuk, ukonci, zastavi alebo stisi mediaPlayer
@Override
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
    switch (focusChange) {
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
            if (mediaPlayer == null) initMediaPlayer();
            else if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.pause();
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
            break;
    }
}

//metoda na ziskanie AudioFocusu/priority hrania zvuku
private boolean requestAudioFocus() {
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
    return result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED;
}

//metoda ktora odstrani audioFocus
private boolean removeAudioFocus() {
    return AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED == audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
}

@Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {

}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    skipToNext();
    buildNotification(PlayStatus.PLAYING);
}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    switch (what) {
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
            Log.d("Media Player error", "MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK" + extra);
            break;
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
            Log.d("Media Player error", "MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED" + extra);
            break;
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
            Log.d("Media Player error", "MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN" + extra);
            break;

    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
}

@Override
public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
}

class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    MediaPlayerService getService() {
        return MediaPlayerService.this;
    }
}


//inicializacia mediaPlayeru, ak sa nenastavi cesta vyhodi chybu a zastavi sa
private void initMediaPlayer() {
    if (mediaPlayer == null)
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.reset();

    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        // nastavi cestu k hudbe
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(activeAudio.getData());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        stopSelf();
    }
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
}

//nastavenie funkcie tlacidla play
private void playMedia() {
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

//nastavenie funkcie tlacidla stop
private void stopMedia() {
    if (mediaPlayer == null) return;
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}

//nastavenie funkcie tlacidla pause
private void pauseMedia() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        resumePosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }
}

//nastavenie funkcie tlacidla resume
private void resumeMedia() {
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(resumePosition);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

//inicializuje prhravac, ak neziska audiofocus alebo cestu k hudbe zastavi sa
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try {
        Ulozisko ulozisko = new Ulozisko(getApplicationContext());
        audioList = ulozisko.loadAudio();
        audioIndex = ulozisko.loadAudioIndex();

        if (audioIndex != -1 && audioIndex < audioList.size()) {
            activeAudio = audioList.get(audioIndex);
        } else {
            stopSelf();
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        stopSelf();
    }

    if (!requestAudioFocus()) {
        stopSelf();
    }

    if (mediaSessionManager == null) {
        try {
            initMediaSession();
            initMediaPlayer();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            stopSelf();
        }
        buildNotification(PlayStatus.PLAYING);
    }

    handleIncomingActions(intent);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

//metode prida zrusenie audiofocusu a nastavi prehravac na null, vypne phoneStateListener, odregistruje recievre, zmaze notifikaciu a vycisti playlist
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        stopMedia();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
    removeAudioFocus();

    if (phoneStateListener != null) {
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }

    removeNotification();

    unregisterReceiver(jeNahlasReciever);
    unregisterReceiver(playNewAudio);

    new Ulozisko(getApplicationContext()).clearCacheAudioPlaylist();
}


//ked sa vyberu sluchadla tak sa hranie zastavi
private BroadcastReceiver jeNahlasReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        pauseMedia();
        buildNotification(PlayStatus.PAUSED);
    }
};

private void registerJeNahlasReciever() {
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY);
    registerReceiver(jeNahlasReciever, intentFilter);
}

//metoda ktora zisiti v akom stave je hovor, a ked telefon zvoni alebo prebieha hovor, zastavi prehravanie
private void callStateListener() {
    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        pauseMedia();
                        hovor = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        if (hovor) {
                            hovor = false;
                            resumeMedia();
                        }
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }
    };
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}

//ked prepnem pesnicku tak sa pomocou tejto metody resetne prehravac a prepne na dalsiu pesnicku podla indexu ktory dostala v sprave
private BroadcastReceiver playNewAudio = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 //            if(status == PlayStatus.PAUSED) {
            audioIndex = new Ulozisko(getApplicationContext()).loadAudioIndex();
            if (audioIndex != -1 && audioIndex < audioList.size()) {
                activeAudio = audioList.get(audioIndex);
            } else {
                stopSelf();
            }

            stopMedia();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            initMediaPlayer();
            updateInfo();
            buildNotification(PlayStatus.PLAYING);
 //            } else if (status == PlayStatus.PLAYING){
 //                pauseMedia();
 //                updateInfo();
 //                buildNotification(PlayStatus.PAUSED);
 //            }
    }
};

private void registerPlayNewAudio() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MainActivity.Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO);
    registerReceiver(playNewAudio, filter);
}

//skontroluje ci mediaSessionManager existuje
//vytvori mediaSession a da mu controller
private void initMediaSession() throws RemoteException {
    if (mediaSessionManager != null) return;

    mediaSessionManager = (MediaSessionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE);
    mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplicationContext(), "Prehravac");
    transportControls = mediaSession.getController().getTransportControls();
    mediaSession.setActive(true);
    mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

    updateInfo();

    mediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onPlay() {
            super.onPlay();
            resumeMedia();
            buildNotification(PlayStatus.PLAYING);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            pauseMedia();
            buildNotification(PlayStatus.PAUSED);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipToNext() {
            super.onSkipToNext();
            skipToNext();
            updateInfo();
            buildNotification(PlayStatus.PLAYING);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipToPrevious() {
            super.onSkipToPrevious();
            skipToPrevious();
            updateInfo();
            buildNotification(PlayStatus.PLAYING);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            removeNotification();
            stopSelf();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(long pos) {
            super.onSeekTo(pos);
        }
    });
}

//updatne aktualne info o pesnicke
private void updateInfo() {
    Bitmap albumArt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);

    mediaSession.setMetadata(new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
            //.putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, albumArt)
            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, activeAudio.getArtist())
            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, activeAudio.getAlbum())
            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, activeAudio.getTitle())
            .build());

}

//metoda ktora prepne pesnicku na dalsiu, ak je pesnicka posledna tak ju nastavi na prvu v zozname

private void skipToNext() {
    if (audioIndex == audioList.size() - 1) {
        audioIndex = 0;
        activeAudio = audioList.get(audioIndex);
    } else {
        activeAudio = audioList.get(++audioIndex);
    }

    new Ulozisko(getApplicationContext()).storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);

    stopMedia();
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    initMediaPlayer();
}

//metoda ktora prepne pesnicku dozadu, ak je na zaciatku zoznamu tak ju nastavi na poslednu
private void skipToPrevious() {
    if (audioIndex == 0) {
        audioIndex = audioList.size() - 1;
        activeAudio = audioList.get(audioIndex);
    } else {
        activeAudio = audioList.get(--audioIndex);
    }

    new Ulozisko(getApplicationContext()).storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);

    stopMedia();
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    initMediaPlayer();
}


//metoda ktora spravi v notifikacnom panely prehravac a vzdy ked sa vola tato metoda tak sa v notifikacii updatne info o pesnicke
private void buildNotification(PlayStatus playStatus) {
    int notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause;
    PendingIntent playAleboPause = null;

    if (playStatus == PlayStatus.PLAYING) {
        notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause;
        playAleboPause = playbackAction(1);
        status = PlayStatus.PLAYING;

    } else if (playStatus == PlayStatus.PAUSED) {
        notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_play;
        playAleboPause = playbackAction(0);
        status = PlayStatus.PAUSED;
    }

    Bitmap albumArt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setShowWhen(false)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2))
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            //.setLargeIcon(activeAudio.)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_headset)
            .setContentText(activeAudio.getArtist())
            .setContentTitle(activeAudio.getTitle())
            .setSubText(activeAudio.getAlbum())
            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous, "previous", playbackAction(3))
            .addAction(notificationAction, "pause", playAleboPause)
            .addAction(ic_media_next, "next", playbackAction(2));

    ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());

}

//zmaze notifikaciu
private void removeNotification() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}

// nastavenie akcie na tlacidla v notifikacii
private PendingIntent playbackAction(int cisloAkcie) {
    Intent akcia = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
    switch (cisloAkcie) {
        case 0:
            akcia.setAction(ACTION_PLAY);
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, cisloAkcie, akcia, 0);
        case 1:
            akcia.setAction(ACTION_PAUSE);
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, cisloAkcie, akcia, 0);
        case 2:
            akcia.setAction(ACTION_NEXT);
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, cisloAkcie, akcia, 0);
        case 3:
            akcia.setAction(ACTION_PREVIOUS);
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, cisloAkcie, akcia, 0);
        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
}

//metoda zisti ktora akcia je aktualna a zavola metodu cez transportControls
private void handleIncomingActions(Intent playbackAction) {
    if (playbackAction == null || playbackAction.getAction() == null) return;

    String akcia = playbackAction.getAction();
    if (akcia.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PLAY)) {
        transportControls.play();
    } else if (akcia.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PAUSE)) {
        transportControls.pause();
    } else if (akcia.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_NEXT)) {
        transportControls.skipToNext();
    } else if (akcia.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PREVIOUS)) {
        transportControls.skipToPrevious();
    } else if (akcia.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_STOP)) {
        transportControls.stop();
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: minimize app mean background or killed state ?

Comment: @MageshPandian i mean that i have my app running and i want to listen to music and start facebook for example. And it is killing my app. I found that i should make startForeground(ID, Notification) in my buildNotification method but problem is that i dont have second parameter notification i have just id

Comment: you can play your music in service

Comment: @MageshPandian as you can see i have created MediaPlayerService and  i play music from there, or do you think anythink different?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to `startForeground()`

```
Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_icon)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.title))
            .setContentText("");
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultIntent.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ParentStack.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int mId = 1489;
    startForeground(mId, mBuilder.build());
```